# Insert new contact

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, crm, alexacrm-toolkit

I m using https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit to send data from a form to an entity in CRM
I want to add a product id from entity 'new_produituic' to 'contact' entity

```
<?php 
require 'autoload.php' ;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\EntityReference;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client as OrganizationService;
use AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Settings;
$options = [
'serverUrl' => 'https://xxxx/',
              'username' => 'xxx',
              'password' => 'xxx',
              'authMode' => 'xxx',
              'ignoreSslErrors' => true

];
$serviceSettings = new Settings( $options );
$service = new OrganizationService( $serviceSettings ); 
$guid="00f1b74b-645c-e911-80c1-005056aa3849" ;   
$contact = $service->entity('contact');
 $contact->firstname='testproduits';
 $contact->new_produit_demande= new EntityReference('new_produituic',$guid);
 $contactId = $contact->create();
```

i m expecting to add a contact that the field first name is "testproduits" and the field "new_produit_demande" is the guid

Comment: any errors that you see?

Comment: this is the error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\SoapFault' with message 'Principal user (Id=0fdb9f17-4c5c-e911-80c1-005056aa3849, type=8) is missing prvAppendTonew_produituic privilege (Id=9f11bbd6-dcab-4764-9dbc-86fa5657f02a)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\uic\alexacrm\php-crm-toolkit\src\Client.php:1159 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\uic\alexacrm\php-crm-toolkit\src\Client.php(2011): AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Client->getSoapResponse('https://mycrm.u...', '<s:Envelope xml...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\uic\alexacrm\php-crm-toolkit\src\Client.php(1679)...

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This is permission/privilege issue. The error saying `'Principal user (Id=0fdb9f17-4c5c-e911-80c1-005056aa3849, type=8) is missing prvAppendTonew_produituic privilege (Id=9f11bbd6-dcab-4764-9dbc-86fa5657f02a)'` which means the user you are using `'username' => 'xxx',` all of the security roles are missing `AppendTo` privilege on `new_produituic` Entity.

To compete this below step - you should have System Admin/Customizer role.

Go to any of the security role of that user which is a huge matrix, click the `Custom entities` tab, look for `new_produituic`Entity row and `AppendTo` column, if you keep clicking the small circle you can furnish the privilege like full green circle (whole org) of half orange (same BU) based on your need.

[Read more](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/business-administration/security-roles/)

Comment: @AbdoMErzouk glad to help, pls mark it as answer as well to help others